# is COBOL still worth learning

Tags: cobol

I want to know the answer to this question from a technical point of view,
[Is COBOL still worth leaning?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/247/18098)

What I mean is this: there are some languages you can learn to become a better programmer, for example leaning the assembler can help to understand how a computer work, or learning a functional language when you know an OOP language can teach you to look at programming from another point of view, another way of thinking. Does COBOL have such an advantage?

Comment: I'm not sure this can illicit anything but opinion and debate. You *can* learn about how a processor works by learning Assembler, but you don't really have to. If you've only done OOP, then looking at *anything* else will give the same "different way of thinking", for those concerned to think.

Comment: @BillWoodger I was giving those just as an example, of course people don't have to learn assembler, but they could be better programmers by doing so, and the functional languages was also just an example, I could have mentioned any other type of programming. I just wanted to know if learning cobol would make me a better programmer like assembler did or like learning many paradigms did.

Comment: Perhaps Programmers.SE would be a better place for such a discussion, but even this is somewhat dubious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learning COBOL is just about the money...

COBOL is actively used in big financial or policy cooperations which have their system from the 80ths and wont want to change it.

In order to keep their system running and updated they need cobol programmers. But today a lot of these programmers are retiring and a lot are bought back to their jobs while doubling their salary.

COBOL isn't pretty or much fun but you can earn some money with it.

Comment: This is a highly subjective question, and your answer shows that you have not kept up with the advances in the more modern flavors of COBOL.  Here is an example - http://www.microfocus.com/products/micro-focus-developer/visual_cobol/index.aspx.

Comment: Highly subjective to the point of being wrong, or only "right" in highly specific instances. Also not keeping up with the availability of OpenCobol. Download it for free. Use it for free. Even contribute to its development and use. Even not "pretty" or not "fun" returns to the utterly subjective.

Comment: I wasn't aware of these modern implementations. When I hear the word "COBOL" I still connect it with this old and outdated language. But I will take a look at your refereces.

Comment: @Bugabill, how pervasive are the "new" COBOLs?  Not very. If one wishes to make money in COBOL, they'll likely be on a mainframe where .Net and the like don't exist.  My opinion... there is a use.  Some day, banks and insurance companies will want to move their code to another platform... when that day comes, anyone who knows COBOL AND the target language (Java, C#, whatever) will be worth their weight in gold.